# Creating a 2x2 fluid layout and fill the entire screen

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to tackle a seemingly simple problem. I have a request to make a 2x2 box layout that will fill the entire screen, then break down to a single column at a certain width.

The breaking down part isn't really the problem, it's the 2x2 grid that is fluid I'm struggling with.

I've attempted to do it using something like this:

```
.outer-div{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.inner-div{
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.inner-block{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This sort of works, but doesn't seem very fluid. At least, not what I would expect. Is there a better way to accomplish this? Any ideas greatly appreciated!

(picture attached for visual reference)

[image]

**EDIT**
Ok, so I feel like an idiot. The solution I had was working, the problem is I have another div to display some content that is absolute positioned and a fixed height that I'm not sure how to account for. Please see Fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/q2j940r1/1/

Comment: Depends on browser compatibility. Of course there is flexbox, but that is not supported by all browsers yet and also might have some performance issues when resizing a lot.

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock, that was my bad. Re-typed my example above from memory and thought of that after adding. Edited post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to set all the container elements to `height:100%`, including `html` and `body` tags. And set 50% of width and height for each item.

**[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5jh2m0kd/)**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    font-size: 0; /*fix inline gaps*/
    height: 100%;
}
.item {
    font-size: 16px; /*reset font size*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto; /*for scrollbar*/
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; /*stretch and fill*/
}
.item:nth-child(1) { background: aqua; }
.item:nth-child(2) { background: lime; }
.item:nth-child(3) { background: gold; }
.item:nth-child(4) { background: teal; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="content">A - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention a crucial problem I was running into, I actually have another div with 100% width and fixed height at the bottom of the screen. My goal was to push the four blocks up by this amount, and make sure they fill the entire area. You can see an example in the updated description where I added a Fiddle link. But since I asked the question poorly, your answer is correct in terms of how it was asked. Accepting as correct, but feel free to try and tackle the other problem if you feel like ;)

Comment: No worries, you could use calc() [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jh2m0kd/1/), or use CSS table layout [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jh2m0kd/2/).

Answer (score 2):

This is a question strongly depends on your implementation.

You want a tabellar 2x2 solution with many div, working in any position and environment. I can suggest to directly use TABLE as container in 2x2 layout with:

> - position absolute
> - width/height 100%
> - no margin/no border

more simple you talk to browser, more simple render you get, this is my advice

Comment: The easiest solution in my honest opinion

Answer (score 1):

#### 2x2 Grid Layout:

I have created a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9pzvf6nb/

You can also check out the code snippet bellow:

```css
.col-1 {
    background: blue;
}

.col-2 {
    background: gray;
}

.col-3 {
    background: red;
}

.col-4 {
    background: green;
}

html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container div {
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

I think it'll also help to use some sort of responsive grid system like **Bootstrap** or **Foundation**.

**Bootstrap:** http://getbootstrap.com

**Foundation CSS:** http://foundation.zurb.com

Such libraries have built-in 12 grid layouts that'll help you create complex grid based layouts easily and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know of would be to use a little bit of Javascript with jQuery to set the heights of the divs. 
Run the code snippet below or look at https://jsfiddle.net/rce4csfn/ to see that it resizes dynamically based on the window size.

```js
function setHeight(){
    var windowHeight = $( window ).height();
    $('.box').height(windowHeight / 2);
}

setHeight();

$( window ).resize(function(){
    setHeight();
});
```

```css
*{margin:0px;}

.box{
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
}

#one{background:#82FFFB;}
#two{background:#FFE382;}
#three{background:#E1FF83;}
#four{background:#FEBD87;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="one"></div>
<div class="box" id="two"></div>
<div class="box" id="three"></div>
<div class="box" id="four"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to break the blocks in one line at a resolution below particular level.
Here is the fiddle
**jsfiddle.net/s1gfLabf**